# Taiju and Yuzuriha visiting Senku's fake grave in Dr.Stone

Tags: dr.stone

Why would Taiju and Yuzuriha visit Senku's fake grave despite knowing that it's revealed to Tsukasa that Senku is alive?

Comment: It's been a while since I saw it, but as I recall the answer is a combination of (a) for some amount of time, Tsukasa didn't actually know Senku was still alive, (b) making it so that Tsukasa didn't know that *they* knew, and (c) to give them a routine that would make it easier for Senku to contact them secretly later on.